# Edge where two faces intersect

Tags: mesh, edges

I have two faces, one of them is the floor and one of them is a wall. I want the floor the end where the wall intersects with the floor. However, the wall isn't straight.

I made a drawing to illustrate my idea. 
[image]

The red part is the part which I don't want. I want it to be gone. The blue line is where I want an edge.

To make it more difficult, let's say this part is a curve.

I tried to separate each face and then add a boolean modifier, but that didn't work the way I wanted. Picture below. [image]
As you can probably see already, it leaves a big empty hole. I don't want this.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit: 
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHJBaGCZ2z0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I don't think that second image is very clear at showing the result.

Comment: Boolean will intersect those 2 planes (even if they're planes) just nicely. Set it to BMesh in the recent Blender versions. If using Carve solver it will just cut an edge without deleting the rest (so lazy ways with planes won't work, solidifying will be required)

Comment: Okay, I made a video to show what I did. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHJBaGCZ2z0&feature=youtu.be